# Best way to store Excel data and access parts of it

Tags: mysql, sql, database, excel, phpmyadmin

I am looking for the best way to store a set of data on my server, then from within an App I am building, retrieve random parts of that data.  I am building an App that will present the end-user with study related questions.  I have 40 subjects, with 50 multiple choice questions per subject, a few sample questions for each subject and only 1 correct answer per question.  I have been considering using phpMyAdmin going down the SQL route, but considering I already have all of my data neatly arranged in an excel sheet with columns for '**Subject**' '**Sample question bank**' '**Real question bank**' '**Answer bank**' with the respective excel sheets (containing the actual content) listed under the **Sample**, **Real** and **Answer** Question Bank columns.

Is entering in and restructuring manually, all of my data, really the only/best way for me to move forward?  Or is there another method, perhaps one of storing and accessing Excel files on a server, and being able to call data from a given column.  The way my data is arranged, I will never need a specific question, the only pair of data that must match is the proper Answer to a question.  All of my other calls for data within the Application will be random.  i.e. I will be populating the App with 20/30/40 random questions from within a particular subject.

I apologize in advance if I am violating any rules or if my etiquette is improper.  Thanks very much for anyones input or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Import your existing spreadsheet into mysql.

Create a table with the specified column names.
From Excel save as CSV file

install mysql, if you haven't
setup admin account.
launch mysql

to import the CSV.

from mysql use INFILE

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

and your whole spreadsheet is now in mysql.

Then use php or perl to make a web-based interface.  Of course, other programming languages are just as good.